# oid and bytea are creating system in tables

Tags: postgresql, oid, bytea

oid -> creates a table pg_largeobjects and stores data in there 
bytea -> if the compressed data would still exceed 2000 bytes, PostgreSQL splits variable length data types in chunks and stores them out of line in a special “TOAST table” according to https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/binary-data-performance-in-postgresql/

I don't want any other table for large data I want to store them in a column in my defined table, is that possible?

Comment: "*is that possible?*" - not if you want to store more 2K data in a single column

Comment: All that you write about is Postgresql housekeeping that happens under the hood. On the SQL level you do "store them in a column in my defined table" jsut as you want.

Answer (score 2):

It is best to avoid Large Objects.

With `bytea` you can prevent PostgreSQL from storing data out of line in a TOAST table by changing the column definition like

```
ALTER TABLE tab ALTER col SET STORAGE MAIN;
```

Then PostgreSQL will compress that column but keep it in the main table.

Since the block size in PostgreSQL is 8kB, and one row is always stored in a single block, that will limit the size of your table rows to somewhat under 8kB (there is a block header and other overhead).

I think that you are trying to solve a non-problem, and your request to *not* store large data out of line is unreasonable.